# Instantaneous change in DC electronic load power

Tags: dc-dc-converter, transient, electronic-load

I am attempting to observe current transient behavior for a DC-DC converter when the loading changes instantaneously. For example, I want to observe current transients at the output of the converter when the DC electronic load changes from 2 A to 8 A instantaneously.

Is there a good method for performing this test? Can I make use of a transistor somehow?

Comment: I assume you have an oscilloscope? Because you're going to need one. Yes you can use a transistor to switch in and out a load. Rather than switching in and out a load, it would be smoothest to switch another resistor into parallel with the first resistor which is always connected.

Comment: Nothing changes instantaneously.  You mention a step load change of 2 A to 8 A.  What is the time for this load change? 100 ns? 1 uS? 1 ms?

Comment: You also need to make sure you account for your wiring inductance, wiring capacitance, and load capacitance.  All of these affect the step response of your power system.

Answer (score 1):

There are two aspects to this. First is the speed (rate) at which the load transient is applied. Some (generally lower voltage, for processors) are designed for load transients of full load in << 1 us. Second is the accuracy of the transient -- generally this is not critical as the transient response for 2..8 A will be similar to that for 2..9 A etc.

DC electronic loads are not fast enough to generate transients that slew faster than ~ ms. To apply a faster load, use a MOSFET with a resistor (say VOUT/ILOAD/2) in its source. You can often drive the FET with a signal generator. Adjust the high and low levels so that the load levels are what you desire.

If this is a low voltage output (say < 3 V), then inductance of jumper cables will actually limit the di/dt you can generate. In extreme cases (10's of A in 100s of ns) you need to put the FET on the DCDC output board within a few cm.

Comment: Re: "To apply a faster load, use a MOSFET with a resistor (say VOUT/ILOAD/2) in its source. You can often drive the FET with a signal generator. Adjust the high and low levels so that the load levels are what you desire." – 
Are you suggesting to scrap the DC e-load and just use an array of resistors and MOSFETs? Like Figure 1 in this datasheet? [https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slva716a/slva716a.pdf?ts=1667178771201&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F]

Comment: That data sheet is for a different application (switching a power supply to different loads). Yes, use FETs + resistors if you want to observe transient response; electronic loads are not fast enough.